# How can I deliberately create and echo in my headset's microphone?

Tags: windows-8, audio, software-rec, skype, microphone

As odd as it may seem, I actually want someone I'm communicating with via VoIP (namely Skype) to hear what I'm hearing out of my headset's speakers. Is there a program that will allow me to do this with my USB-based headset? I mean, sure, I could just use a really loud speaker and put the volume at 11, but what if I wanted to do this in a library setting (just for instance, not that I'm actually at a library)?

I've done some googling and couldn't find a solution that way. I don't really know of any other way to solve my problem outside of asking.

As always with me, polite criticism on my question is welcome, as is, obviously, help with my actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your headset is using 3.5mm socket and not operating via USB you could use a double adapter (available from electronics or hifi store) which will create two outputs for your headset sound. Then basically use a set of headphones that are patched into one of the sockets and stick it close to the input of your headset. It should give you what you're looking for for less than $5.